# How to exit/skip outter do-while after finishing If-Then in nested(inner) do-while

Tags: vba, exit, do-while, worksheet

I am a newbie to VBA dealing with some real-work problem, I have a problem exit do-while after finishing the inner(nested) do-while.

*The code works fine, there is no issue, but I want to know how to make it more efficient by exit/skip outter do-while once the inner if-then is matched and ## is done.

here is what the code looks like(FYI I delete some codes for ease of reading) :

```
 For Each w In Worksheets  
    If () Then

       Do While (i)  ' outter do-while

            Do While ()   'inner(nested/1st do-while)
                    If () Then  'match something here

                        ## do something here

                        Exit Do      'break the inner do-while
                    End If

            Loop

            i = i + 20   'question here!!how should I break outter do-while?

        Loop                       
     End If
  Next w
```

So, my goal is that once if-then is matched and ##content is done, how could I directly go to "next w", aka jump to next worksheet?

I tried "goto+line" but it doesn't work, is there another way?

Comment: add additional `variable` of `Boolean` type. Set it `true` inside `inner loop if statement`. Next, in outer loop check if this `variable = true` and if so call `exit do` for outer loop.

Comment: thank you Kazi! That's very helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try something like this:

```
Dim exitLoop As Boolean '<--| default initial value is 'False'

For Each w In Worksheets
    If () Then

        Do While (i) And Not exitLoop  ' outer do-while

            Do While () and Not exitLoop 'inner(nested/1st do-while)
                    If () Then  'match something here

                        ## do something here

                        exitLoop = True
                        Exit Do      'break the inner do-while
                    End If

            Loop

            i = i + 20   'question here!!how should I break outter do-while?

        Loop
        exitLoop = False '<--| set back default value
     End If
 Next w
```